# Detect onLongPress in Particular LinearLayout in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I want to detect onLongPress event with in particular layout.In my xml LinearLayout with in the RelativeLayout.I want to get the onLongTouch with in the LinearLayout only.I try to using onTouchEvent this works well, but onLongPress working on hole layout including RelativeLayout. If I put `return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);` with in the `myLinear.setOnTouchListener`.It turn into single Touch.Please help me to solve this problem.Any reply I am very appreciate.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLinear"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/floorimg">

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout myLinear;
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myLinear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinear);
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());

    myLinear.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });

}

/* @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}*/

private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Long press called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [`OnLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) with you LinearLayout:

```java
myLinear.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long press called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Bro exactly I want zoom the LinearLayout and add multiple pinmarks. So I asked this.I already tried this.First we get the x and y coordinate and add the pinmark. onLongClickListener can call only one time on the Layout.Can you refer another option?